# Finding the probability that two real numbers chosen at random satisfy a set of conditions (specific problem included)

Tags: probability

There's this easy question that's been bugging me all day long and I would be very thankful if somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong when attempting to solve it.

The problem goes: 'Two real numbers are chosen at random from the interval $I = (-1,1]$. If it is known that their sum is a negative real number, what is the probability that the first number is larger than $1/2$ and at the same time, its square is smaller than the second number.'

What I've tried to do so far:

> - Let A be the event: 'The first number is larger than 1/2; i.e $x>1/2$'.
> - Let B be the event: 'The square of the first number is smaller than the second number; i.e $x^2 < y$'
> - Let C be the event: 'The sum of the two numbers is a negative real number; i.e $x+y<0$'
>
> We're trying to find $p((A*B)|C)$, which, if I got this right would be
>   $p(A*B*C)/p(C)$. However, unless I'm mistaken, this won't work. I
>   tried to draw a geometrical representation using Cartesian
>   coordinates, but so far I only got that there's no way that A and
>   B can be true if C is also true.

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the probability is 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you're doing wrong is not believing the answer that you obtained.  As you say, there's no way that A and B can be true if C is also true.  That says $P(ABC) = 0$, so $P(AB|C) = P(ABC)/P(C) = 0$.

Comment: I didn't completely discard the idea that the probability might be zero based on observation, but I wasn't exactly sure either, as I'm pretty new to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the method would use conditional probability, and then integrate the joint probability over the appropriate domains.  Except...  as you say, those bounds contradict.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(x>1/2 , x^2<y\mid x+y<0 ) & = \frac{\mathsf P(x>1/2, x^2<y, y<-x)}{\mathsf P(x+y<0)}
\\ & =\frac{\int_{1/2}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{-x}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\operatorname d y \operatorname d x}{\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^{-x} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x}
\\ & = 0
\end{align}$